# Selecting Multiple Text Boxes

Tags: class, textbox, height, width, selector

I was wondering if there is a way to change the height and width of both text boxes. I tried:

```
.class{width:200px;height:100px;}
```

But it has no effect. Is there anyway I can select both without having to type:

```
#firstname, #lastname{width:200px; height:100px;}
```

Here is the code:

```
<div class="info">
<input type="text" id="firstname" >
</div>
<div class="info">
<input type="text" id="lastname" >
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.info input {width:200px;height:100px}
```

Comment: Oh haha. Thanks. I had another quick question. When do you use div id vs div class? In the code I typed, is class correct?

Comment: they have a very similar function, with one exception - IDs can only be used once on the page, classes can be used any number of times. i tend to just use classes, but you can do your basic layout with IDs, then your styling with classes - so, #header, #footer etc, and then .box, .column, .whatever for the inside bits. however you prefer working.

Comment: hey, can you accept this as an answer if you're happy? :) click the big tick!